# How to configure fail2ban for both TCP and UDP port?

Tags: networking, 20.04, bind, fail2ban

I want to ban some DNS requests coming to my *named* server. The server normally listens both TCP and UDP port 53 and logs the requests to `/var/log/named/query.log` file. So, I added the following entry to the end of `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[named-xyz]
enabled  = true
port     = domain
filter   = xyz
logpath  = /var/log/named/query.log
bantime  = 1d
action   = %(action_)s
```

However, this only bans the TCP port (by default). To ban the UDP port also, I need to add another entry:

```
[named-xyz-udp]
enabled  = true
port     = domain
protocol = udp
filter   = xyz
logpath  = /var/log/named/query.log
bantime  = 1d
action   = %(action_)s
```

Having to similar entries may not look overkill, however it has a drawback of logging double entries for a *single "bad" request* to the `fail2ban.log` file like this:

```
fail2ban.filter         [11619]: INFO    [named-xyz-udp] Found a.b.c.d
fail2ban.filter         [11619]: INFO    [named-xyz] Found a.b.c.d
```

How can I simply ban both UDP/53 and TCP/53 at the same time with a *single rule* in `jail.local`? A `protocol = all` line does not work in my case.

*fail2ban* version is `v0.11.1`.

Answer (score 0):

> A `protocol = all` line does not work in my case.

It depends from the banning action you use.
What do you mean as "does not work"?

For actions (like `iptables-allports` accepting `all`) it may be enough to set that this way, for other action (which accepts multiple protocols, like `nftables`), it can be set with `protocol = tcp,udp` (or whatever separator they'd need instead of comma).
For the actions which doesn't accept multiple protocols (like `iptables-multiport`) one need to specify 2 actions, here is an example working for newest fail2ban versions - https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/10cd81552538fa950cefc32787b9f82b5ee1b998/config/jail.conf#L748-L749

For older fail2ban versions which does not accept interpolation of `%(default/action_)s` or multiple parameters `[...][...]` you need to set something like this:

```
action = %(action_)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, protocol="tcp"]
         %(action_)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, protocol="udp"]
```

(or by fail2ban 0.9.x even replace `%(action_)s` with its [whole definition](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/10cd81552538fa950cefc32787b9f82b5ee1b998/config/jail.conf#L212) from default section):

```
action = %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-tcp, actionname=%(__name__)s-tcp, protocol="tcp", port="%(port)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
         %(banaction)s[name=%(__name__)s-udp, actionname=%(__name__)s-udp, protocol="udp", port="%(port)s", chain="%(chain)s"]
```

Comment: I am sorry, I could not follow your answer, since I am not expert on fail2ban. What would be your suggestion for modifying the first entry (in my Question)? Putting a two-line `action =` as you suggested gives the error: `option 'action' in section 'named-xyz' already exists`

Comment: you have to put 2 actions with a single parameter `action`, see my example - so 2 lines, but second line without `action =`, just with few spaces; and ensure you don't have already specified an `action` in the section for jail `named-xyz`.